# How to raise value in one table using two tables IN SQL?

Tags: sql, sql-server

How can I properly raise prices of products in Beverages category with 2 %.
These tables are found in https://northwinddatabase.codeplex.com/ Northwind (SQL)database

My non-working query:

```
UPDATE products
SET unitprice = unitprice * 1.02
FROM products, categories
WHERE categories.categoryID = products.categoriesID
AND categories.categoryname LIKE '%Beverages'
GROUP BY products.categoryID;
```

Comment: Which dbms are you using? That UPDATE FROM syntax is product specific.

Comment: What error you are getting after running the query?

Comment: @jarlh . . . "Northwind" pretty much implies SQL Server.

Comment: @GordonLinoff, perhaps there are people not knowing that.

Answer (score 0):

There is no need for the `GROUP BY`:

```
UPDATE p
    SET price = price * 1.02
    FROM products p JOIN
         categories c
         ON c.categoryID = p.categoriesID
    WHERE c.description LIKE '%Beverages';
```

If more than one category could match a single product, the above would still only increase the value by 2% (rather than 2% for each match).  However, I would recommend `EXISTS` rather than a `JOIN`:

```
UPDATE p
    SET price = price * 1.02
    FROM products p JOIN
    WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 1
                  FROM categories c
                  WHERE c.categoryID = p.categoriesID AND
                        c.description LIKE '%Beverages'
                 );
```